# How to align text right justified in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have below text link list appearing in a col-md-3. I want to appear them as right-justified. See attached image below.

Current Coding is like below with "text-right" in the col-md-3, I tried text-justify too didn't seem to be working,

Any idea on how to make this the way i wanted as the image?Should i use a `'<ul>'` or `'<li>'` instead?

```
<div class="col-md-3 mt-2 text-right">
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <b>View Profile</b>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-12">   
         <b>Send Message</b> 
      </div>
   </div>
   ....
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <b> View Proposal </b>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: For me your code is working just fine. https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/jOWmqLe

Comment: @Shnigi I want it "RIGHT JUSTIFIED", not right-aligned, see the red line in the image, that's where i want it to be aligned from.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `text-right` on the container. Instead, turn the `col-md-12` divs into `col-md-6` and use an `offset` i.e. `offset-6`. Now the element takes up 6 columns and is offset 6 columns, which puts it to the right of it's parent element.

More information about offsets can be found about halfway down the [Bootstrap Grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Here's the code demonstrating how to do this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 mt-2 container">
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-6 inner">
         <b>View Profile</b>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-6 inner">   
         <b>Send Message</b> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-6 inner">
         <b> View Proposal </b>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Here it is on Codepen](https://codepen.io/nick_kinlen/pen/KKVmRXq)

Comment: isn't this same as having two columns of col-6 col-6? this works only on certain occupations like col-md-6 but don't work or not consistent on other devices like xs,sm ...etc

Comment: Bootstrap allows you to set multiple widths for different screens i.e. you could use something like `col-md-6 offset-md-6 col-lg-4 offset-lg-8` for larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

I Just updated my Codepen: https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/jOWmqLe
It really depends how you want to place your grids and how much content they are going to have.

```
<div class="col-md-12 row">
   <div class="col-md-3 offset-9 text-right">
         <b>View Profile</b>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 row">
   <div class="col-md-3 offset-9 text-right">   
      <b>Send Message</b> 
   </div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-md-12 row">
   <div class="col-md-3 offset-9 text-right">
     <b>View Proposal</b>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here I have created three rows which all span 12 columns. Then inside the rows I have element which spans 3 columns and has offset of 9 totalling 12 columns. Then I have placed text-right to make the text float on right inside the 3 column element.